Why must empty rules be inserted in syntax-directed translation of a control-flow grammar?
In Engineering a Compiler (Cooper, Torczon) 3rd Edition, Chapter 5 Syntax-Driven Translation, Section 5.3.3 Translating Control-Flow Statements, the following nested control-flow grammar is presented,
1 Stmt  --> if Expr then Stmt
2   | if Expr then WithElse else Stmt
3   | Other
4 WithElse --> if Expr then WithElse else WithElse
5      | Other

Posed with the problem of using the actions within a syntax-directed translation to emit three-address IR code, the authors find a problem:
"Production 4 [...], shows the issues that arise in a translation scheme to emit
[a form of three-address] code for an if–then–else. Other productions will generate
the IR to evaluate the Expr and to implement the then and else parts. The scheme
for rule 4 must combine these disjoint parts into code for a complete if–then–else.
...
"The complication with rule 4 lies in the fact that the parser needs to emit IR
at several different points: after the Expr has been recognized, after the WithElse
in the then part has been recognized, and after the WithElse in the else part has
been recognized. In a straightforward rule set, the action for rule 4 would execute
after all three of those subparts have been parsed and the IR for their evaluation
has been created."

I am confused as to why this constitutes an issue. What exactly is wrong with just waiting for the production that recognizes Expr and the inner WithElse's to be parsed and have IR emitted? Why can production 4 not simply rewrite the IR to insert jumps, branches, and associated labels?
